# MySQL Count Rows with Two Cells the same

Tags: mysql, php

I have a db where the cells are height and width. (It's for banner ads)
Some banners are the same width, but different height, or visa versa.
for example:
row1 hieght = 600 width = 120
row2 hieght = 600 width = 120
row3 hightt = 600 width = 90
row4 height = 125 width = 125
etc

I want to know how many rows are 600x120, how many are 600x90, etc

How do I fix the sql query as follows to get the info I want?

```
$sql="SELECT  COUNT(`height`) GROUPED BY (`width` ) 
FROM  `rv_banners` 
WHERE 1 " ;
```

Answer (score 3):

What about something like:

```
select
  height || 'x' || width as dimensions,
  count(*) as number_of_banners
from
  rv_banners
group by
  height, width ;
```